# Can I put Security Groups into OU

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, organizational-unit

Can I put a Security Group inside an OU?

If I put specific users into an OU, the GPOs applied to the OU works fine. If I put a Security Group (that contains the users) into the OU, the GPOs don't work.

If I can't (as I belive), how can I add a lots of users into an OU?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear to me what it is you're trying to accomplish but you cannot apply Group Policy to security groups (despite the name). Group Policy can be filtered based on security group membership, but GPO's themselves apply to computers and users. That being said, your GPO needs to be linked to the OU where the user objects exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a security group inside an OU, but this doesn't cause linked GPOs to apply to the users and computers inside that security group. GPOs are only applied to users and computers contained directly within the OU-Domain-Site hierarchy.

One reason you might *want* to locate a security group under an OU would be to delegate control of the entire OU, including security groups contained therein.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply GPO's to security groups. The computer configuration part of the GPO will apply to computer objects directly under the OU. The User configuration will apply to user objects directly under the OU that has been linked.

If you need to apply a GPO to a group of users that is not based on your OU structure, you can do this through security filtering, but this is NOT reccomended. Security filtering introduces inefficiencies into Group Policy.

Comment: *Security filtering introduces inefficiencies*...do you have a source you can cite for this?

Comment: I will look for a source. It has to do with the login process, and each client trying the policy and getting denied at each processing occurrence. Similar to why it is reccomended to ten settings in one GPO, rather than create ten GPOs with one setting each. Not a large hit by any means, but just a best practice.